# Particles casting shadows of plane?

Tags: particles, lighting

[image]

Why is the particles, rocks in these case, that are on the bottom plane have those squares around them? the problem is those are casting shadows of squares on render view, how do I remove them, I am kinda new to particles

Comment: Hi. I don't see any shadows in your screenshot nor any planes around particles

Comment: It looks like you added an area light to a collection that is being instanced for particles (thus making many "particle" area lights in addition to the rocks). Move the light to a different collection.